# Optimize a moving average

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have written code that calculates a weekly exponential moving average, providing a value for each day. To achieve this, I compute the value for day 'd' by using the most recent value of the weekly exponential moving average from the dataframe, which includes data up to and including day 'd'

I have the following code:

```
def weekly_exponential_moving_average(data: pd.DataFrame, window: int, column: Optional[str] = 'Close_Price') -> pd.Series:

def compute_ema_for_day(day):
    day_before_d = data[data.index <= day][column]
    weekly_data = day_before_d.resample('W').last()
    return weekly_data.ewm(span=window, adjust=False).mean().iloc[-1]

weekly_ema = data.index.to_series().apply(compute_ema_for_day)

return weekly_ema
```

which gives the desired result: it calculates the weekly moving average over a window of the data[column].

Yet this code is highly inneficient, because compute_ema_for_day run every time through the whole time serie.

Is there a way to calculate what I want in more efficient way (like linear time?)?

Comment: are you sure this calculates what you want it to calculate? I think you want the ewm for each day of the week separately . This is not what your function does since it calculates the ewm based on the value of the current weekday and the values of past sundays .

Comment: @algebruh Yes this is exactly what I want!: "it calculates the ewm based on the value of the current weekday and the values of past sundays". Sorry if I wasn't clear in my post, so now that it calculates this I am wondering if it is posisble to optimize this function

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no elegant and fast way to do this in pandas. I think you have to write the exponential moving average class yourself and a custom for loop. It may look like this:
(according to some test data it returns the same values as your function)

```
import pandas as pd

class ExponentialMovingAverage:
    def __init__(self, alpha : float):
        self.current_value = None
        self.alpha = alpha

    def update(self, value, update_current_value = False) -> float:
        if self.current_value is None:
            self.current_value = value

        new_value = self.alpha * value + (1 - self.alpha) * self.current_value
        if update_current_value:
            self.current_value = new_value

        return new_value

def get_ewm_values(ewm: ExponentialMovingAverage, df: pd.DataFrame, column='Close_Price'):
    values = []
    for index,row in df.iterrows():

        sunday_index = 6
        day_of_week = index.day_of_week
        if day_of_week == sunday_index:
            ewm_value = ewm.update(row[column], True)
        else:
            ewm_value = ewm.update(row[column])
        values.append(ewm_value)
    return values


emv = ExponentialMovingAverage(0.5)
df['ewm'] = get_ewm_values(emv, df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yeah actually this might be the only way of doing it, I don't find exactly the same result though, for example using: np.random.seed(0)

start_date = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
num_dates = 100
date_list = [start_date]
for _ in range(num_dates - 1):
    date_list.append(date_list[-1] + timedelta(days=np.random.randint(1, 4)))

close_prices = np.random.rand(num_dates) * 100

df = pd.DataFrame({'Close_Price': close_prices}, index=date_list)
print(df)

Comment: it's because there can be missing dates in my datframe

Comment: yeah I see. you would need to adjust the class then. Not sure how the pandas implementation deals with irregularly sampled series though... 

Just curious, why do you want to calculate this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I thing filtering is unnecessary. You can resample and return weekly ema:

```py
def weekly_exponential_moving_average(data: pd.DataFrame, window: int, column: Optional[str] = 'Close_Price') -> pd.Series:

    weekly_data = data.resample('W').last()
    weekly_ema = weekly_data.ewm(span=window, adjust=False).mean()
    return weekly_ema
```

or if you need the same shape as input, you can map the weekly_ema dataframe to the original `data` dataframe.

Comment: no but this doesn't give the same result, as my function above. As I said I have a different value for every day, which is clearly not the case with the function you provided since it's constant on weeks

Comment: I don't get it, because of this line> weekly_data = day_before_d.resample('W').last() could you provide with sample data